# How to chage the font style of default spinner in android studio?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to change the font style of Default spinner in android 
please guide me how ca I do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a custom xml file for your spinner in which you can set textSize and textcolor according to your requirements. For the font style, you would first need to go to res folder and right click on it and then choose Android resource directory. In the resource type list, select font. Then add your font files to the font folder created under res. Then simply use this in your custom spinner XML file.

```
android:fontFamily=@font/"name of your font file"
```

Try this out it might work.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom ArrayAdapter with your own layout.

Here is an example:

```
public class ShippingMethodSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourModel> {

    public ShippingMethodSpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context,
                                    @NonNull List<YourModel> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.shipping_method_spinnert_item, objects);
}

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return itemView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return itemView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    private View itemView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shipping_method_spinnert_item,
                parent, false);
        }

        TextView txtShippingMethod = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtShippingMethod);
        txtShippingMethod.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }


}
```

YourModel can be something like this:

```
public class YourModel {

    private String title;
    private String value;

    public ShippingMethodSpinnerModel(String title, String value) {
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then add this adapter to your spinner

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```